# Private enum access fails to compile from a nested class's friend function

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, inner-classes, friend, access-control

I am currently porting a project that has so far only been built using Clang, to also work with GCC. The project contains code similar to below and compiles fine with Clang, however GCC gives an error message.

```
class Outer
{
  enum
  {
      ONE, TWO, THREE, COUNT
  };
public:
  class Inner
  {
    friend class Outer;
    friend void somefunc()
    {
      int x = Outer::COUNT;
    }
  };
};
```

The error is:

```
<source>: In function 'void somefunc()':

<source>:15:32: error: 'Outer::<unnamed enum> Outer::COUNT' is private within this context

   15 |                 int x = Outer::COUNT;

      |                                ^~~~~

<source>:6:26: note: declared private here

    6 |         ONE, TWO, THREE, COUNT

      |                          ^~~~~
```

Note the friend keyword in the `somefunc` signature. Removing this makes the code compile fine with GCC, I'm wondering which compiler is correct? I am under the impression that friend functions have the same access as member functions which would make this a GCC bug.

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/OAR0gc

Comment: I think the main problem is that once you make `somefunc` a friend function, it will lose the otherwise automatic access to the embracing class' private members.
Either remove the `friend` keyword or make `sumefunc` the friend of the `Outer` class as well. (So that it can access it's enum.)

Comment: @Gyebro I see, so you would say that GCC is correct and Clang is exhibiting incorrect behaviour?

Comment: @nitronoid I think that GCC is correct, as the inline declaration of the friend function is still considered to be outside the class scope. [Inline friend definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/friend-cpp?view=vs-2019#inline-friend-definitions). If `somefunc` is friend of `Outer`, it works as expected: https://godbolt.org/z/3AkKUP

Comment: I say it's a GCC bug. If `Inner` has access to `Outer`'s private members, and a function is named a friend of `Inner`, access control should work transitively.

Comment: @0x499602D2 That was my initial feeling.

Comment: Clang also seems to be buggy in this area. If a friend of `Inner` is defined [inside](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2897d53d798c4b3a) the class it can access private members, but if defined [outside](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a566b5ab46c956d) of `Outer` it needs an explicit friend declaration inside `Outer` in order to compile, even though a friend declaration inside `Inner` should be sufficient.

Comment: @0x499602D2 This is quite compelling evidence for Clang being at fault, nice find.

Answer (score 0):

This is the age-old question of whether the body of a friend function declared-in-line, being lexically part of the class in which it's declared, has access to all names that the class has access to. The last time this was discussed by CWG, in 2021, there was no consensus as to which interpretation of the standard is correct. This is [issue 1699](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1699).

Interestingly, some compilers have changed their opinion since this question was posted. As of October 2022, Clang and GCC will compile the code when the friend function is defined inline, while MSVC will not [[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/x8GKxr974)]; all 3 compilers reject the code when the friend function is defined out-of-line [[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/11a8WP7db)].

Answer (score -1):

```
friend class Outer;
```

1. Is not needed, nested class has access to private members of embracing class.

```
friend void somefunc()
```

2. According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend point 2, function that member of "Inner" and friend can't get privilege from point 1. Remove friend keyword.

Comment: Do note that this question is tagged as [tag:language-lawyer] so answers should be supported with quotes from the C++ standard to support them..

Comment: 1) may not be needed for this minimal example, but it is still valid, and doesn't affect the resulting error. 2) Yes as I stated in the question, removing the friend keyword gets rid of the error, you seem to suggest then that Clang is incorrect?

Comment: According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend point 2 you shouldn't define member friend.

Comment: @MateuszWojtczak I think what point 2 says is that the function is not a member when marked with the friend keyword. It doesn't say you "shouldn't" do it, and I'm not trying to define a member function anyway.

Comment: @nitronoid You shouldn't do it if you want to have access to private members of Outer. Also if you are not trying to define member why do you expect that it will have access to private member of Outer?

Comment: @MateuszWojtczak I know that removing the friend keyword gets rid of the error with GCC, you repeated what I already have in the question. I am asking which compiler gives the correct result, Clang or GCC. I don't "expect" anything, I have only reported that Clang allows it and GCC does not.